# c++ templates double constructor call

Tags: c++, templates

Hi I am new in C++ templates, need some help with it.
Code below kind of static polymorphism. Problem with Token type that, double calls Token constructor and destructor.
How achieve one call for constructor, destructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> class Scalar {
private:
    T s;
public:
    using value_type = T;
    Scalar (T const& v): s{v} {std::cout<<"Scalar const\n";}
    ~Scalar() { std::cout<<"Scalar destruct\n";}
    T const& operator [] (size_t) const { return s; }
    size_t size() const { return 0; }
};

template<typename T> class Token: private T {
public:
    using value_type = T::value_type;
    Token (typename T::value_type val): T(val) { std::cout<<"token constructor\n"; }
    Token (Token const& rhs) = delete;
    Token (Token&& rhs) =default;
    ~Token () { std::cout<<"token destruct\n"; }
    decltype(auto) operator [] (size_t idx) const 
        { std::cout<<"token const ref\n"; return static_cast<T const*>(this)->operator[](idx); }
};

template<typename T> std::vector<Token<T>> tokens;

template<typename T> void add_scalar (T value) {

    tokens<Token<Scalar<T>>>.emplace_back(value);
    std::cout<<"val " << tokens<Token<Scalar<T>>>[0][0]<<'\n';
} 

int main () {

  add_scalar<int>(10);
}
```

That return

```
Scalar const
token constructor
token constructor
token destruct 
token destruct
Scalar destruct
```

Comment: You should be outputting the value of `this` inside the constructors and destructors, not just a simple message.  Then you will know when, where, and which constructors/destructors are being called.

Comment: [C.46: By default, declare single-argument constructors explicit](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#c46-by-default-declare-single-argument-constructors-explicit)

Comment: [Different output here](https://godbolt.org/z/MnM947fKP)

Comment: Missing `typename`, `using value_type = T::value_type;` should be `using value_type = typename T::value_type;`

Comment: Did you do test a release build? I have seen cases where debug builds do not use copy elission and extra copies are made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tokens<Token<Scalar<T>>>` is a `std::vector<Token<Token<Scalar<T>>>>`. This means when you `.emplace_back(value)`, you create a `Token<Token<Scalar<T>>>` that holds a `Token<Scalar<T>>` as a base class, so there are two `Token<...>` objects.

It might be a bit more clear if you spelled out the template types in the functions (https://godbolt.org/z/4Kd4e9b6K):

```cpp
Scalar<int>(int const&) constructor
Token<Scalar<int>>(int) constructor
Token<Token<Scalar<int>>>(int) constructor
Token<Token<Scalar<int>>> destruct 
Token<Scalar<int>> destruct
Scalar<int> destruct
```

Two constructor calls and destructor calls would be the lowest amount to add an item to `tokens<Token<Scalar<T>>>`. Though the double `Token<Token<...>>` is a bit fishy, perhaps you meant `tokens<Scalar<T>>`.